# How to remove HTML Tags and '\n' from Scrapy Python Output

Tags: python-3.x, web, web-scraping, scrapy, web-crawler

I'm new to Python and Web Scraping. I wrote below 2 lines to extract title and price from website. However it gives output with html tags and '\n' characters. 
How can I remove them and get only text output?

```
product_name = response.css('#productTitle::text')[0].extract().strip('\n')
product_price = response.css('#priceblock_ourprice')[0].extract().strip()
```

---

Output

```
[
    "                \n                    \n                    \n                \n\n                \n                    \n                    \n                        Stainless Steel Food Grinder Attachment fit KitchenAid Stand Mixers Including Sausage Stuffer, Dishwasher Safe,Durable Mixer Accessories as Meat Processor\n                    \n                \n\n                \n                    \n                    \n                \n            ",
    "<span id=\"priceblock_ourprice\" class=\"a-size-medium a-color-price priceBlockBuyingPriceString\">$87.99</span>"
]
```

Answer (score 1):

Removing extra spaces an `\n`:

```
for text in str_list:
    text = text.replace("\n","") #remove all '\n' from text
    while "  " in text : # if 2 space symbols in sting
        r_str = text .replace("  ", " ") # replace 2 spaces with 1 space and repeat until no more 2 consecutive spaces in text
```

Second selector also should have `::text` in selector: 
`product_price = response.css('#priceblock_ourprice::text').extract_first()`